# Opening a PDF file stored in a jar file with the desktop's default app

Tags: java, file, jar

I'm nearing the end of a program development for my computer science course. However, one of the requirements is to have a user manual within the app. I saved the user manual as a PDF inside Eclipse's workspace.
It is stored under "/Documents/PDF Manual.pdf". I originally used this code:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource( fileSeparator + "Documents" + fileSeparator + "PDF Manual.pdf");
           //fileSeparator = '/' on mac, & '\\' on windows
        File userManual = new File (url.toURI());
        if (userManual.exists())
        {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(userManual);
        }
```

This works fine while running the project from eclipse, however URI returns a non hierarchical exception (as expected) when the program is exported to a jar file. I thought of playing around with url.toString(), using substring and replaceAll() to get rid of unwanted characters (%20 for the space), however this gave weird results and of course the code wouldn't work properly when it wasn't a jar file.

I looked at InputStream, however this is only used to read from a file and I cannot open the file using a desktop app.

Due to the process of submission, the pdf HAS to be saved inside the project folders.

Also, my code has to be platform independent (or at the very least, work on windows and mac) and thus manipulating file names becomes a lot more complicated. Any suggestions?

### Edit:

After @SubOptimal 's help, this is the code I am now using:

```
String inputPdf = "Documents" + fileSeparator + "PDF Manual.pdf";
        InputStream manualAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(inputPdf);

        Path tempOutput = Files.createTempFile("TempManual", ".pdf");
        tempOutput.toFile().deleteOnExit();

        Files.copy(manualAsStream, tempOutput, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        File userManual = new File (tempOutput.toFile().getPath());
        if (userManual.exists())
        {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(userManual);
        }
```

This works on mac. However, on windows manualAsStream is null for some unknown reason.

Comment: I guess you need to extract first the PDF from your JAR file to a temporary location (system property `java.io.tmpdir`). As the desktop application might not be able to open files inside an archive.

Comment: @SubOptimal The error is returned when creating the new file with `url.toURI()`, as such I can't place the PDF inside the temp folder because I cannot reach its path at all while it is in the JAR. Am I correct in thinking that I would have to call `Files.copy()` to place the pdf in the temp directory?

Comment: The solution in Edit is working for me in Windows also, although 5 years later. It's never too late!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full working example. Tested in Windows environment.

**file structure**

```
.\REPL.java
.\doc\manual.pdf
.\manifest.mf
```

**REPL.java**

```
package sub.optimal;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.awt.Desktop;

public class REPL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputPdf = "doc/manual.pdf";
        Path tempOutput = Files.createTempFile("TempManual", ".pdf");
        tempOutput.toFile().deleteOnExit();
        System.out.println("tempOutput: " + tempOutput);
        try (InputStream is = REPL.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(inputPdf)) {
            Files.copy(is, tempOutput, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempOutput.toFile());
    }
}
```

**manifest.mf**

```
Main-Class: sub.optimal.REPL
```

**compile**

```
javac -d . REPL.java
```

**create JAR**

```
mkdir dist\
jar cvfm dist/REPL.jar MANIFEST.MF sub/optimal/REPL.class doc/manual.pdf
```

**execute JAR**

```
cd dist\
java -jar REPL.jar
```

Comment: It took a bit of messing around, but I managed to get it to work ! Thank you ! I actually had to indicate the path starting at the Documents folder for the pdf manual, or 'InputStream' would be null. Very simple to get it to work with `.open()` however. Thanks !!

Comment: After further testing, the code does not work on windows for some reason. All of my other code regarding file saving which follows the save logic is fine, but this one does not open the PDF file. From what I can tell, it doesn't even create a temp file. The input Stream seems to end up being null. I had a similar problems on mac at first, however I managed to get around that by changing the path of the file. This does not work on windows.

Comment: Ok, now it works across both mac and windows. I tracked down the issue to be with the use of my fileSeparator variable (\\ for windows). I didn't know you could use unix-like notation for windows based file systems. Thanks for your help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead of getResource

To write in the temp directory use [createTempFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)