# .jar works correctly if I manually place PDFs in the dist folder. After clean and build, the files go and the app loses some functionality

Tags: java, netbeans

I have 6 PDFs that load via 6 individual buttons. This is just a side function to view the data I used to create the program.

The program runs as expected in the IDE, the PDFs load smoothly and the main program works.  However, after a clean and build, the main program still works but the PDFS do not load.

I have noticed that if I manually place the PDFs in the dist folder after a clean and build, the program actually runs I expect.  However, if I then clean and build again, it obviously deletes and replaces the dist folder contents.

I am in the scenario at college of giving the program to a client, who is my tutor.

I would prefer not to hand him a .jar file with 6 PDFs next to it in the same folder and needed to run the program.

I hope someone with a bit more experience knows why this may be.

My question is.. How do I get the .jar file to include the PDFs automatically. I have tried for 2 days. Placing the PDFs in every possible folder, then cleaning and building and running the jar, but still no luck.

Comment: Let's first see in your code how you are accessing these files, please.

Comment: Sure

 if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try{
                File myFile = new File ("A level pre 2017.pdf");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            }catch (IOException ex) {

This is how I am accessing the PDFs.  They are located in the only place that seems to work which is in the main folder, alongside the build, dist, src folders.

I also tried putting a test exception in but it just doesn't seem to throw one.

Comment: You cannot just use, as for an application: 
File file = new File("a.pdf");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
this works to access the local file system

Comment: Thanks raj.  I tried this but it was suggested I replace FileInputStream with URL.  Both produced errors but it will be something on my part, i'll keep trying.

Comment: So don't place them in the `dist` folder, or make copying them there from some other place part of your build process.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Source folder of your project and copy all Pdf's in that folder. 
In NetBeans, any resources you place in the src tree will be automatically copied over to the classes tree when you do a Build (or Clean and Build), except those files matching the "Exclude From JAR File" skeletons specified in Project -> Properties -> Build -> Packaging. So if you pasted it there it should be in your jar file even after clean and build.

and to handle the pdfs you can see the process in below links.
http://www.coderanch.com/t/456579/java/java/open-pdf-file-located-jar

[Opening a PDF file stored in a jar file with the desktop's default app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806965/opening-a-pdf-file-stored-in-a-jar-file-with-the-desktops-default-app)

code:

try {

```
Path tempOutput = Files.createTempFile("tempFile", ".pdf");
tempOutput.toFile().deleteOnExit();
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/yourfile.pdf");// here u can provide path to ur file as a String.
Files.copy(is,tempOutput,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
{
    Desktop dTop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if(dTop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN))
    {
        dTop.open(tempOutput.toFile());
    }
}
```

} catch (IOException ex) {}

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it but the buttons produce errors even in the IDE run if the files are placed anywhere other than the main folder that includes src as a sub-folder.  I've looked on every article I can find and just  can't seem to figure it out. I'll try that article now.

Comment: What is the Exception that is generating when you click the button.

Comment: If, i move the files into the src folder i get the following error...   
                     
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: A level pre 2017.pdf doesn't exist.     Also, I am unsure how to properly post code neatly on here as I am a new user

Comment: I think the error is because of getDesktop#open only allows files to be opened from the file system. however you can do work around by creating temp file and copying your pdf contents into tempfile and try to open it. I have updated the code in above comment for opening pdf